# rspec test of index, show all not archived

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

Im trying to set up a (basic) test for a new feature I am going to implement. I have a job controller and instead of default showing all jobs I like to hide all the ones which is archived. I tried different ways but it seems like i am missing a piece or two of this puzzle. First i tried with calling 'visit' but get the message it does not exist. Second approach is using 'render' but that also ends up in a error saying render does not exists. (can i even use these methods in a controller spec?)

Is it wrong to put this in a controller test?

2 last test are causing errors

```
require "rails_helper"
require "spec_helper"


describe JobsController, :type => :controller do 

  context 'GET index' do   
   it "should be successful" do
     get :index
     expect(response).to be_success
   end

  it "renders the index template" do
   get :index
   expect(response).to render_template("index")
 end

 it "should not show any archived jobs as default" do
    visit jobs_path
    page.should have_no_content("Archived")

 end

  it 'should show the headers' do
    render :template => 'job/index', :layout => 'layouts/job'
    rendered.should_not contain('Archived')

  end

 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara is used for feature specs, and its matchers can be used in view specs.
Controller specs, by default, don't actually render the view because they're the wrong place to be checking for page content - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs
You should probably move some of your tests to feature tests/view tests